# Inner-loop using vector.size() leads to infinite loop

Tags: c++, loops, vector

I am trying to avoid copying with vectors, so I am (I know -- poor practice) mutating the vector while I loop over it, but I have noticed that it evaluates size() at every loop end. Furthermore, even if I declare it outside of the loop and assign it to another variable, it still reevaluates. Even more surprising, even if I declare it const, it reevaluates. Can someone tell me why this is the case? And what is the best way to add to a vector without creating a separate one, then combining them after each inner loop completes? Sample code:

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v {0};
    // infinite loop
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        const size_t sz = v.size();
        for (size_t j = 0; j < sz; ++j)
            v.push_back(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the strange idea that it "reevaluates" it? No, it doesn't reevaluate the size in the code above. Your code *doubles* the size of the vector 100 times. Can you image what the final size is going to be? This is probably greater than the number of atoms in the Universe.

Comment: Your vector is doubling in size each inner loop.  Do you have enough RAM for 2 ** 100 ints?

Comment: You do not have an infinite loop, simply change your outer loop's `i < 100` to `i < 10` and you will see. You simply think it is infinite because the number of executions is very large.

Comment: You vector is going to be: `0 0 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...`. Is that what you want?

Comment: In my actual code, I had a condition on the inner loop so that it wasn't appending exponentially. However, the condition was based on a user-defined operator+, which was accidentally returning a bool rather than int, so it was constantly executing the conditional and appending.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to avoid memory reallocation with vectors.
If this is the case you should use reserve(n): it preallocate memory for n elements thus avoiding memory reallocation while it have n elements or less. When you reach n+1 elements it may reallocate.
I'd like to ask you to be more specific: what are you expecting from your code?

Comment: `thus avoiding memory reallocation until it have n elements or less` shouldn't until be while?